# CSS class automatically sizing width to 100%, and I do not want it to do that

Tags: css

Apologies for the strange diction in the title.

I'm having a problem with a site I'm designing. I'm using WordPress, but I don't think that's the issue.

The problem is, I have a "Module" class which is supposed to wrap to its contents. Instead of wrapping, however, it by default stretches to 100% of its parent's width. When I manually enter the appropriate width, the right margin still stretches to the right side edge of its container. When I manually resize the margin, nothing changes.

Here's the module class, just because:

```
.module
{
margin:0px;
padding:5px;
background:#356;
border:#38a solid 1px;
}
```

It's simple enough. However, I want it to be wrapped to its contents. Instead, it's automatically sizing itself to stretch to 100% of its parent.

I've scoured my both my stylesheet AND Chrome's element inspector, and cannot for the life of me figure out what's going on.

Comment: What is the tag that .module is attached to?

Comment: Look at the differences between block level and inline elements: http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm

Answer (score 2):

You're probably adding that class to a [block-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#block-level0) element such as a div or a paragraph. Block-level elements have `display: block` by default, therefore they stretch to the width or their parent.

You can use `display: inline-block;` to change that behavior:

```
.module {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #356;
    border: 1px solid #38a;
}
```